# Add heading numbers not working in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to add numbers to the headings of my Word file. I'm using Word 2016 with the latest updates.

At first I put the cursor in the first heading, and then I added the "list with more level" feature. Like following:

First Step:

[image: First Step]

Result:

[image: Result]

In the Navigation Pane you can see, that these are headings.

How can I automatically create all Numbers?

Answer (score 0):

[How to Create a Multi-Level Numbered List in Word 2016](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-multilevel-numbered-list-in-word-2.html)

This Site will teach you how and you can use Increase Indent or Decrease Indent in order to have the corresponding level.
You can select all the text and click on the corresponding list you need.
[image]
When the List is wrong (Feature most be 1.1 for example) Click on Feature to put the Insertion point near it, then click on Increase Indent to move the indent right and change the number, or Decrease Indent will move the text left and decrease the List Level.

[image]

You can always use none to remove all the numbering

Comment: link only answers are discouraged in superuser, please quote relevant parts in your answer.

Comment: This is useless, the OP has already created the full document and wants to be able to just add numbers to all existing headings, without having to make further edits.